# Access to a SharePoint intranet page from application

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, html-agility-pack, intranet

I'm trying to fetch data from a page that resides on an intranet. The intranet is based on SharePoint. The address look like this: http://collab.intranet.com/Pages/Default.aspx.

I'm using the HTML Agility Pack (.NET) to fetch the data, which I've got working on external webpages but not the intranet. I have access to the intranet page through my browser.

**Edit: So the question is:** How do you grant access to a program that needs access to a SharePoint intranet page?

The code I'm using to retrieve data (C#):

```
String webpage = "http://collab.intranet.com/Pages/Default.aspx";
String mainTarget = "table";
String mainAttribute = "id";
String mainId = "activeProjects";

var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(webpage);

var partOfWebpage = from completeWebpage in document.DocumentNode.Descendants(mainTarget)
                            where
                                 completeWebpage.Attributes[mainAttribute] != null &&
                                 completeWebpage.Attributes[mainAttribute].Value == mainId &&
                                 completeWebpage.Attributes[mainAttribute].Value != null
                            select completeWebpage.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: I bet on authentication missing. Can you grab the content using WebClient.Download method ? What is the http status in case of an error ?

Comment: Steve B, i believe you're right. I tried it with the WebClient method and received **"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"**. What can I do to authorize the C# session? 

I've added the code I'm using.

Comment: Also, I think the intranet is based on SharePoint. Is it possible to grant the exe file permissions maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution after some digging around and trial & error. Since the intranet is based on SharePoint it's possible to use the **WebService library** and make calls to the 'SharePoint Lists'. But i also found that the following code gave me access to the SharePoint page:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

I was then able to download the page as a string with the help of the client and then passing it through the *HTML Agility Pack* to do what i wanted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to do so since I had to wait 24 hours before i was able to accept the answer :)